# Unexpected end of file upon view of Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing an e-commerce website based in Laravel. I have the following file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-XdYbMnZ/QjLh6iI4ogqCTaIjrFk87ip+ekIjefZch0Y+PvJ8CDYtEs1ipDmPorQ+" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {{-- <link href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> --}}

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .fa-btn {
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="app-layout">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                @if(!Auth::guest())
                    <span class="icon-bar"><a href="/cart">Cart</a></span>
                @endif
                @if(Auth::user()->user_level == 1)
                    <span class="icon-bar"><a href="item/create">Create item</a></span>
                    @end
            </button>v

            <!-- Branding Image -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                Laravel
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('auth/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('auth/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                @else
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

@yield('content')

<!-- JavaScripts -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{{-- <script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script> --}}
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run any page in my local browser I get the following error message:

> 1 FatalErrorException in 12864a26e90179d06aed7c0f8dcccf47c0f50961.php line 86: syntax error, unexpected end of file

I'm not sure if it's  because I'm using model references. I'm still new to Laravel and am not sure where the error lies in my syntax or the use of models in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a syntax error on the following line:

```
@if(Auth::user()->user_level == 1)
   <span class="icon-bar"><a href="item/create">Create item</a></span>
@end
```

Should be `@endif` instead of just `@end`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I fixed that error and now I'm getting another one: "Trying to get property of non-object" same code

Comment: Are you "logged in"? if not, then the problem is being caused by the same line as before `@if(Auth::user()->user_level == 1)`. If your not "logged in" then `Auth::user()` is not an "object", hence the error when calling the `user_level` property. Try this: `@if(Auth::check() and Auth::user()->user_level == 1)`, that will check to see that the user is logged in before trying to access properties on the user object...

Comment: That seems to be what the problem is. Should have to do with my Auth

Comment: @TomMorison Accept the answer if it has fixed your issue